# how to call NSStream Synchronously

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asynchronous, ftp, nsstream

How to call NSStream synchronously to get the results??

Presently I am getting a async call back in one of its delegate methods

```
 `(void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent`-
```

Comment: why would you want to get streaming data synchronously?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `NSStream` is an abstract class that neither reads or writes data to a stream. To actually access the data you'll need a concrete subclass such as `NSInputStream` or `NSOutputStream` (or your custom subclass of `NSStream`). To read the data in an `NSInputStream` call `read:maxLength:`. You'll probably want to poll the stream, asking it if any new data is available, with `hasBytesAvailable`. An NSOutputStream has analogous `write:maxLength:` and `hasSpaceAvailable` methods.

You are highly encouraged by the iOS documentation to avoid polling, and use run-loop scheduling instead by responding to the async call back delegate methods.

Comment: If you are running in a separate thread it is not necessary to poll. You can just read from the input stream and it will block until there is data available/stream is closed/error occurs. Responses emulate posix behaviour, where 0 means stream closed, -1 means an error occurred. A positive number means actual bytes read from stream.